# How to Apply Conditional Formating with Multiple Rules to all other cell using drop down list

Tags: vba, excel

Hy Experts, I have an excel sheet with different data columns. I have a column with status name. This contain drop down list with different text values. I implement different conditional formatting rules on one cell and apply it to entire row of that cell. Please review my sheet below.

[image]

It is implement successfully, and work fine. Here is conditional formatting rules.
[image]
The remaining rules are here.

[image]

These are total 8 rules.

Now the problem is that When I copy the above cell and paste it below the conditional formatting does not work. While I also changed the range from the cell in conditional formatting manager, but it is not working.

How I am apply it to all below cell range upto 25000 while I can't wrote it for everyone.

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: try removing the absolute cell references in `$K$3`. So just `K3` in the formula for conditional formatting.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman bro I used the same setting but it not resolved...

Comment: any one plz help

Comment: Just edited my answer. See if that helps.

Comment: @K.Davis bro I did as you explain one by one. As it should to be work but I tried it again and again but nothing happened. Actually I want to implement the same formatting to every row in my sheet. I also used the Formatting Tool of excel but it only implement the current background colour not whole condition as behind working with others.

Comment: Is there any solution of this problem?

Comment: After passing three days there is not solution available of my problem... I am still waiting for its resolution.....

Answer (score 0):

Remove the anchor for the rows in your formulae, so instead of `=$K$3=*something*`

```
=$K3=*something*
```

and extend the Applies to range, so instead of `=$A$3:$K$3`, something like:

```
=$A$3:$K$25000
```

Both for *each* rule.